# Why is the contact form barely visible? We want the contact form to be white and brighter

Tags: javascript, html, css

Our contact form is barely visible. We can't figure out what's going on... if you go to the page you'll see what I mean. Github page: https://tcffo.github.io/

[image]

Comment: Did you try giving some background to your form.

Comment: try to add a background-color four the input or form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border for your input fields have an opacity of 0.2 and it's a grey color. I'd change the border to white and the opacity to 1 `border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1)` and also add a background-color as suggested by others here, for instance `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2)`. I hope this helps. The existing CSS for your input-fields are found on line 1720 in main.css.

Comment: I would also add some rules for the width of your input fields. You can target the form wrapper that has ID #contact-form:
   `#contact-form{max-width:32rem; margin:1rem auto;}`

Answer (score 0):

give background color to your form or form wrapper 
or
give border to your form elements

You can apply below two rules or one of them

```
<style>

/*Background for your form*/

#contact-form{
   background-color:#YOUR_COLOR;
}

/*Border for form elements*/
#contact-form input{
   border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has no definitive answer, but some options to make your form clearer are to:

- not have an image underneath your form at all
- bolden the text
- blur and possibly darken the background (like frosted glass)
- block out or darken the background just underneath the form controls

The first and last options are the best in my opinion. The reason they're so dark is because they're placeholder values, and making them white, the same colour as your input text, is a horrible idea because then it becomes unclear if the text is just a placeholder or not.